# How to use Pattern matching in test class for email field?

Tags: apex, unit-test, email

I am using pattern matchers for the email filed in contact in my development. When writting the test i am getting error in that patter matches.Here i have method the error line.Kindly help me to resolve this and tell how to write test for pattern matcher.
In Apex class:

```
email = contact.email;

If( Pattern.matches(('^[_A-Za-z0-9._-]+@test.com.au'), email))
{
         if(booking == 'Team1') {
                    setnon(False);
                    setbuy(True);
                    setRepl(False);
                }
                else if(booking == 'Team2') {

                    setnon(False);
                    setbuy(False);
                    setRepl(True);
                }
                 else if(booking == 'None') {
                    setnon(False);
                    setbuy(False);
                    setRepl(False);
                    }
                }
```

In test class:

```
    @isTest(seeAllData = true)
public class newcont_TestClass
{
    static testmethod void Test1()
    {
            PageReference pg = page.newcont;
            Test.setCurrentPage(pg);
            //To get Account Record Type id f
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult cfrSchema = Schema.SObjectType.Account; 
            Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> AccountRecordTypeInfo = cfrSchema.getRecordTypeInfosByName();

            // To get contact record type
            RecordType rt = [SELECT id,Name FROM RecordType WHERE Name='PS'];

            Account acc = new Account(Name = '190 ', recordtypeid=AccountRecordTypeInfo .get('PS').getRecordTypeId());
            insert acc;
            Account account = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];

            Contact con = new Contact (LastName = 'test', Email = 'test@test.com.au', AccountId= account.id,recordtypeid=rt.id );
            insert con;
            Contact contact1 = [SELECT Id, LastName, Email FROM CONTACT WHERE LastName = 'test' LIMIT 1]; 

            Case case1 = new Case(S_Logged_By__c = 'test',Full_Name__c= 'test',Email_Address__c = 'test1@test.com.au',Contact_Name__c = contact1.id  );
            insert case1;        
            ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('message', 'Record Created Successfully' );

            ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardController (case1);   
            newcont controller = new newcont();
            controller.method1();
            Test.StopTest();

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're querying the same contact and you don't have `SeeAllData=true` for your test method? Also, is this your helper class for a Contact trigger or how does this work? Can you explain a bit more or maybe post the rest of the code?

Comment: @Bachovski Thank for your comment. yes i am using SeeAllData=true.I a m apex class to insert the contact which has the email in the following formate.

Comment: Can you pleas post the whole test method?

Comment: @Bachovski I have updated my code. Inside method1() I have given the pattern macther for the email field.

Comment: From what I can see you're referencing `contact1` in your apex class, which is an existing contact in the system and not the one you're creating. Therefore I am not sure if contact1's email address matches that pattern. Also please check the field level security for the email field on the contact and ensure it's visible to the user's profile which is running the test method.

Comment: @Bachovski I have updated my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15972/discussion-between-lavanya-sanathkumar-and-bachovski).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion and looking at the whole (massive) controller, the issue was that your case variable was private and you were setting the case email field based on a URL parameter.

Solution:

Either make your case variable public and set the email field on it before calling the method that you're testing, or, specify the URL parameter in your test class before you call the test method:

```
PageReference pg = page.newcont;
Test.setCurrentPage(pg);
...
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('email', con.Email);
DC controller = new DC();
controller.method1();
```